# Pagination in Angular Ionic with next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I display a list of data on my page.
Now the client says display one and then add next and previous button for prev and next.
Angular pagination without adds any packages.

my code is.

```
        <div *ngFor="let l of list">        
            <ion-card mode="ios" *ngIf="l.data!=null">
                <ion-card-content>
                  <div class="ion-des" [innerHTML]="l.data| safe"></div>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </div>
```

and my typescript code is

```
 getMenu() {
    this.api
      .get(
        'GetMenuData'
      )
      .then((data: any) => {
        this.list = data.data;
      });
  }
```

JSON-

```
 "Tabledata": [
              {
                "id":"01",
                "data":"Smith"
              },
              {
                "id":"02",
                "data":"Smith2"
              },
              {
                "id":"0",
                "data":"Smith3"
              }
            ]
```

Now-

[image: Now]

I need this way-

[image: wanted]

Instead of data 1, data 2, data 3, ..., data n
I need to add data 1 and Next and Previous btn on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is "pagination".

In my opinion a good approach is that your API only returns one item instead of a list.
But your API needs a option to take additional query parameters like `?page=2` or `?limit=1&offset=1` which both would return the second item.

Then you do not need to loop through the list but you only get one item and show it as a card. With a click on the `next` button you call your API with `?page=3` and get the next item.

To show `Page 2/10` on every page you need to return the total amount of pages too.

**Alternative**

You load the whole list on page load and only show one item at a time. If you click on next, show the next item in the array.

Comment: I got a list of data in Get API. So first I need to display the first one on the card. and when press next displays second and for previous display back data.   It just likes a blog

Comment: your alternate option is good `but how to do that?` Thank!! @Ma Kobi